# How to convert NPN transistor to PNP transistor?

Tags: arduino, transistors, npn, pnp, hall-effect

I am making a circuit using a **4 pin hall sensor** with arduino. It turns out that the hall sensor outputs a negative voltage as output, which arduino cannot read, so I will need a **PNP** transistor, I don't have one but I have a bunch of NPN (BC547) laying around. Is there any way I can make a PNP transistor or add circuitry to make the NPN into PNP? Thanks in advance.
*For more info about the hall sensor, the first pin is +ve second is Normally open third is Normally closed and fourth is -ve*
[Schematic](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10_PsR07OCImzm6FjJkDNPMAR9MkEIy0E/view?usp=drivesdk)

---

Turns out that I have a pnp transistor with my Snap Circuits kit. I cracked it open, soldered some wires and now, it looks like this [image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10WxAsk4zBRIKppivORqjTU1djqPF01rx/view?usp=drivesdk)
Take a look at my Schematic above and tell if I need another resistor or somethin

Comment: I also want to make a circuit with arduino and a ir sensor which also turns out that it outputs negative voltage. So I need this very badly

Comment: In principle, you can do it. Show us the circuit.

Comment: Wrong question - you want to convert your signal to something useful for the Arduino. Converting pno into npn is not the issue.

Comment: Tell us exactly which hall sensor you're using, and give us a link to the datasheet. Someone here will figure it out for you, and most likely you don't need any transistors at all.

Comment: you can probably connect that sensor directly, but you haven;t described it in enough detail for me to say how.

Comment: Can you explain more closely what signal range your sensor generates? It's very unlikely its output is outside the range of GND-VCC

Comment: Short answer: you can't switch transistor polarity. Also I *really* doubt your sensor is giving out a negative voltage (a JFET could be the solution in that unrealistic case). Do you have a datasheet for the sensor?

Comment: The hall sensor is used in pc fan and I am not able to find a datasheet. What I do know is it's behaviour, it closes Normally open when it is exposed to the North pole of a magnet and opens it when its exposed to south pole.

Comment: @Lorenzo Marcantonio -ve voltage means ground

Comment: Schematic has been uploaded

Comment: @Bheeshma: The schematic is private on your Google drive - no one else can see it.

Comment: @Bheeshma - Please stop using Google Drive links for your schematics. (a) As already commented, you are providing *private* links, which means we cannot see your schematics. (b) When those links become unavailable in future, then the question becomes useless. || Therefore please use the site's built-in image upload capability. Click [edit] then hit Ctrl+G (on a PC) (or click the "mountains" icon above the edit box) and follow the on-screen instructions to upload the image(s). Images need scaling to be no larger than 2MB before uploading. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No. You can't change an npn transistor into a pnp transistor.

Comment: Well a Sziklai pair sort-of does but I don't think that mentioning that will help the querant.

Answer (score 3):

NPN transistor can't be converted into PNP transistor. This question is already discussed here. [How can I convert a PNP to NPN transistor?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/51434/how-can-i-convert-a-pnp-to-npn-transistor)